# Error 400 al procesar la solicitud de plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, jquery-plugins

tengo un problema al procesar una solicitud de un plugin de WordPress, este plugin lo que hace es en el checkout en la casilla de teléfono valida si el numero de teléfono tiene WhatsApp, el plugin funcionaba correctamente cuando realizaba la consulta con una API, pero lo que se intenta implementar es trabajar con 2 API y que se pueda seleccionar cual API usar para la validacion pero en el momento de implementar me sale error 400, comparto codigo de la modificacion del codigo donde se implementan las 2 API

```
     function validateWhatsAppNumber(number, callback) {
        var selectedApi = 'api1'; // Por defecto, usamos la API 1. Esto cambiará según 
         la opción seleccionada en el backend.

        // Obtenemos la opción seleccionada en el backend
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: aqui va la api 1,
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',  // Asegurándonos de que es POST
            data: {
                action: 'get_selected_api_option'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response && response.selected_api) {
                    selectedApi = response.selected_api;
                }

                // Definimos las URLs de las APIs
                var url_api_1 = 'aqui va el api 1'; 
                var url_api_2 = 'aqui va el api 2';

                // Seleccionamos la URL basada en la opción
                var apiUrl = selectedApi === 'api1' ? url_api_1 : url_api_2;

                // Realizamos la petición a la API seleccionada
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: apiUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        wa_number: number
                    },
                    success: function(resultado) {
                        callback(resultado);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

si hay algo mas que pueda compartir con gusto lo hare muchas gracias

Comment: por ejemplo decir que recibes codigo 400 no ayuda de mucho ... y no has dado suficiente informacion para poder replicar el error ... entonces  tienes que hacer debug... evalua linea a linea, variable a variable hasta donde llega la ejecucion y si esta tiene lo que esperas ... si el codigo de error es 400 del servidor significa "Solicitud incorrecta" esto quiere decir que no esta recibiendo lo que espera, esto tambien significa que no estas enviado lo que debe de ser ...

Comment: amigo gracias por responder la duda principal es si la logica del codigo que comparto es correcta o tiene algun falla, quedo atento gracias

Comment: no lo se amigo, tu pregunta es aun peor ... como podemos determinar si el codigo es funcional si no podemos reproducir su funcionamiento ...